# Find coordinates of every link in a page

Tags: javascript, web, hyperlink, location

In Javascript:
How does one find the coordinates (x, y, height, width) of every link in a webpage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jQuery, it's as simple as:

```
$("a").each(function() {
    var link = $(this);
    var top = link.offset().top;
    var left = link.offset().left;
    var width = link.offset.width();
    var height = link.offset.height();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

without jquery:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i in links) {
    var link = links[i];
    console.log(link.offsetWidth, link.offsetHeight);
}
```

try this page for a func to get the x and y values:
http://blogs.korzh.com/progtips/2008/05/28/absolute-coordinates-of-dom-element-within-document.html

However, if you're trying to add an image or something similar, I'd suggest using the a:after css selector.

Answer (score 1):

Plain JavaScript:

```
function getAllChildren (node, tag) {
  return [].slice.call(node.getElementsByTagName(tag));
}
function offset(element){
  var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  var docEl = doc.documentElement;
  return {
    left: rect.left + window.pageXOffset - docEl.clientLeft,
    top: rect.top + window.pageYOffset - docEl.clientTop,
    width: element.offsetWidth,
    height: element.offsetHeight
  };
}

var links = getAllChildren(document.body, 'a');
links.forEach(function(link){
  var offset_node = offset(node);
  console.info(offset_node);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```
$j('a').each( findOffset );

function findOffset()
{
    alert
    ( 'x=' + $j(this).offset().left
    + ' y=' + $j(this).offset().top
    + ' width=' + $j(this).width()
    + ' height=' + $j(this).height()
    );
}
```